# ASP - running in localhost - unable to reach internet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localhost, web-scraping

I have an ASP MVC controller action.
I'm trying to make a web request

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
   WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
   string str =  response.ToString();
}`
```

I get a "WebException occured" the remote name could not be resolved: 'www.example.com'

If I start Fiddler, then the webrequest works.

I tried adding:

```
 <system.net>
 <defaultProxy>
   <proxy usesystemdefault ="True" bypassonlocal="True"  />
 </defaultProxy>
```

to Web.config (with and without hte bypassonlocal) and it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the proxy server explicitly:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy proxyaddress="http://proxy.yourcompany.com:80" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

You could also set the proxy programatically:

```
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.yourcompany.com:80", true);
```

When you set `usesystemdefault` to `true`, the application uses the proxy defined in the `Internet Options` dialog box. When you deploy your application in IIS it usually executes under the `Network Service` account which has very limited privileges, it doesn't even have any GUI session so it cannot infer the proxy server.